# Laravel filtering query results with relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[I have this relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOeW7.png)
and defined models for all 3 tables

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'employees';
    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class, 'dept_emp', 'emp_no', 'dept_no', 'emp_no', 'dept_no');
    }
}
class Department extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'departments';

}
class Dept_emp extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'dept_emp';
}
```

And in my controller

```
 $employees = Employee::with('departments')->paginate(50);
```

I want to filter this query result to be able to select only one chosen department and not all of them.

I tried adding to employee model this function

```
    public function scopeDepartment($query, $department)
    {
        return $query->where('dept_no',$department);
    }
```

but it isn't working. Can someone advice me how to filter query results with relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can query within with relation as like

```
$employees = Employee::with(['departments' => function($q) use ($dept_id){
  $q->where('dept_no',$dept_id);
}])->paginate(50);
```

`$dept_id` is the id of department i.e `$dept_id = $request->department_id` something like

Comment: After i used 
```
$employees =Employee::with(['departments' => function($q) use ($dept){$q->where('dept_no',$dept);}])->paginate(50);
```
i got error
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'dept_no' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: and after i changed 'dept_no' to 'departments.dept_no' query worked but this relations was null for every row items[]